# How to debug Vitest test in the browser?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, debugging, vite, vitest

I already failed in webstorm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-56836/Vitest-debugging

So what else should I add to debug tests in the browser? I tried `node --inspect ./node_modules/vitest/vitest.mjs`

If I try the above and have `brave://inspect/#devices` open the test runs but no breakpoints (via debugger statement) are hit.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like it is being handled by the vitest team, they might provide a patch soon: https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/1867